# How to speed up FastAPI - Uvicorn?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FASTApi application, that I'm trying to deploy via Uvicorn Async task using the below cmd:

```
uvicorn app.main:app --host='0.0.0.0' --port=8080 --workers=5
```

My system has below config:
12core, 24threads processor - 32GB RAM - 16GB GPU

I tried to perform load test on one GET & one POST APIs (executing detectron2 and Paddle OCR model predictions). GET takes on avg 3ms and POST takes approx 1.7s-4s. Both my functions/APIs are defined with `async def` prefix

Irrespective of the number of workers(1-8), GET API runs avg 385RPS while POST API runs on avg 3RPS-10RPS. Like even with 5 workers, for POST my RPS is 3. Can't understand why is this happening.

Please suggest where am I going wrong. How can I increase my RPS/throughput? Should I continue to use Uvicorn for production or switch to anything else (production grade)?

Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Tried to update number of uvicorn workers from 1 to 8 (can't go beyond 8 - have processing restrictions).

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 0):

*May be gunicorn running with uvicorn and taking care of workers [fastapi link for gunicorn workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/#run-gunicorn-with-uvicorn-workers)*

Apart from that, I would suggest:

- Find the bottlenecks in the program, where the performance can be
  improved by optimising the code like using `cProfile` .
- Use `asyncio` for parallel computing.

Comment: I did use cprofiler, but it's the ocr and model prediction that takes time. So it's alright.